# Adding array data with in table inserting only single row with in database in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am passing string values with in one variable from ajax and want to insert that string into different row with in for loop right now only single row is inserting with the array having index 1.I have firstly converted string into array and having count to run loop according to count value but only single row is inserting with index 1.For count 2 only single row is inserting.

controller code:

```
public function addSlider(Request $request){
       $addbannerdata = new Banner;
       $noofslides = $request->slidercount;
        $slidername = explode(',',$request->allslidernames);
       $btntitle = explode(',',$request->allbuttontitle);
       $btnurl = explode(',',$request->allbuttonurl);

       //dd($request->all());
        for($i=0;$i<$noofslides;$i++){
         $addbannerdata->banner_title = $request->maintitle;
         $addbannerdata->page_id = $request->pageid;
         $addbannerdata->slider_title = $slidername[$i];
         var_dump($slidername[$i]);
         $addbannerdata->button_title = $btntitle[$i];  
          var_dump($btntitle[$i]);
         $addbannerdata->button_url = $btnurl[$i];
          var_dump($btntitle[$i]);
             $savebannerdata = $addbannerdata->save();
        }

    if($i>$noofslides)
        {
          $result['error'] = FALSE;
          $result['message'] = 'Banner Data  Added Successfully';
        }
      else
       {
          $result['error']  = TRUE;
          $result['message'] = 'Something Went Wrong Please Try Again Later!';
       }
     echo json_encode($result);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This with count($slidername) instead of your for loop condition and put the $addbannerdata = new Banner(); inside your loop otherwise it's only insert single data

```
public function addSlider(Request $request){
  $noofslides = $request->slidercount;
  $slidername = explode(',',$request->allslidernames);
  $btntitle = explode(',',$request->allbuttontitle);
  $btnurl = explode(',',$request->allbuttonurl);

  //dd($request->all());
  for($i=0;$i<count($slidername);$i++){
    $addbannerdata = new Banner();
    $addbannerdata->banner_title = $request->maintitle;
    $addbannerdata->page_id = $request->pageid;
    $addbannerdata->slider_title = $slidername[$i];
    var_dump($slidername[$i]);
    $addbannerdata->button_title = $btntitle[$i];  
    var_dump($btntitle[$i]);
    $addbannerdata->button_url = $btnurl[$i];
    var_dump($btntitle[$i]);
    $savebannerdata = $addbannerdata->save();
  }

  if($i>$noofslides){
    $result['error'] = FALSE;
    $result['message'] = 'Banner Data  Added Successfully';
  }
  else{
    $result['error']  = TRUE;
    $result['message'] = 'Something Went Wrong Please Try Again Later!';
  }

  echo json_encode($result);
```

}

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: Put dd() before your loop and make sure your $slider have more than one array

Comment: no its comming in single array all slider titles in single array

Comment: Can you put $request->allslidernames data in comment then i can ensure why it's not working

Comment: its request data which is passed from ajax and data from ajax is passed in form of array while fetching here its comes in form (adasd1,dasdadasd) in string format

Comment: OOh Dear i have mistake put your $addbannerdata = new Banner(); inside your loop

Answer (score 0):

**Try this .**

```
      public function addSlider(Request $request){
            $addbannerdata = new Banner;
            $noofslides = $request->slidercount;
            $slidername = explode(',',$request->allslidernames);
            $btntitle = explode(',',$request->allbuttontitle);
            $btnurl = explode(',',$request->allbuttonurl);

            for($i=0;$i < count($noofslides);$i++){
                $addbannerdata->banner_title = $request->maintitle;
                $addbannerdata->page_id = $request->pageid;
                $addbannerdata->slider_title = $slidername[$i];
                $addbannerdata->button_title = $btntitle[$i];
                $addbannerdata->button_url = $btnurl[$i];
                $savebannerdata = $addbannerdata->save();
            }

            if($i > $noofslides)
            {
                $result['error'] = FALSE;
                $result['message'] = 'Banner Data  Added Successfully';
            }
            else
            {
                $result['error']  = TRUE;
                $result['message'] = 'Something Went Wrong Please Try Again Later!';
            }
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
```